# Play Notification Sound like a Phone Call Ringtone sound

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am building a prototype in Xamarin.Forms that sends a push notification to the same App installed on other devices. I'm using OneSignal libraries.
Everything works perfectly. The push notification is sent by one device and received by the others correctly. Whether the App is in the foreground or in the background.
When the push notification arrives on the other devices, I capture it in HandleNotificationReceived and call my service that plays the Ringtone sound.
When push notification arrives on other devices and the app is in the foreground, everything works perfectly. However, when it arrives on the other devices, and the App is in the background, only Push Notification arrives, but the Ringtone sound does not play.
I read about limitations when trying to run some things in Background and I believe my problem has something to do with it.
can anybody help me?
Here is my code:

**APPLICATION**

```
    namespace SaferProject
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var page = new NavigationPage(new Views.MainMenu());
            MainPage = page;

            IPlaySoundService playSoundService;
            playSoundService = DependencyService.Get<IPlaySoundService>();

            OneSignal.Current.SetLogLevel(LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, LOG_LEVEL.NONE);
            OneSignal.Current.StartInit("417d7b75-ed42-4ca5-aed3-42612d260235")
            .Settings(new Dictionary<string, bool>() {
                { IOSSettings.kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt, false },
                { IOSSettings.kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL, false } })
            .InFocusDisplaying(OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
             .HandleNotificationOpened((result) =>
             {
                 if (playSoundService.GetServiceStatus())
                 {
                     playSoundService.StopSystemSound();
                 }
                 Debug.WriteLine("HandleNotificationOpened: {0}", result.notification.payload.body);
             })

//################ Here I call the PlaySystemSound service###############
//################ Here I call the PlaySystemSound service###############
//################ Here I call the PlaySystemSound service###############
             .HandleNotificationReceived((notification) =>
             {
                 playSoundService.PlaySystemSound();
                 DeviceDisplay.KeepScreenOn = true;
                 Debug.WriteLine("HandleNotificationReceived: {0}", notification.payload.body);
             })
//########################################################################
//########################################################################
//########################################################################
             .HandleInAppMessageClicked((action) =>
             {
                 // Example IAM click handling for IAM elements
                 Debug.WriteLine("HandledInAppMessageClicked: {0}", action.clickName);
             })
            .EndInit();

            // The promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse function will show the iOS push notification prompt. We recommend removing the following code and instead using an In-App Message to prompt for notification permission (See step 7)
            OneSignal.Current.RegisterForPushNotifications();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            IPlaySoundService playSoundService;
            playSoundService = DependencyService.Get<IPlaySoundService>();
            if (playSoundService.GetServiceStatus())
            {
                playSoundService.StopSystemSound();
            }

            //Handle when your app sleeps
            Task.Run(async () => { await SaferProjectService.GetInstance().GetOut(UserManager.GetLogUser()); });
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            //Handle when your app sleeps
            Task.Run(async()=> { await SaferProjectService.GetInstance().GetOut(UserManager.GetLogUser()); });
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            //Handle when your app resumes
            Task.Run(async () => { await SaferProjectService.GetInstance().GetIn(UserManager.GetLogUser()); });
        }
    }
}
```

**INTERFACE**

```
namespace SaferProject.Services
    {
        public interface IPlaySoundService
        {
            Task PlaySystemSound();
            Task StopSystemSound();
            void SetServiceStatus(bool isPlaying);
            bool GetServiceStatus();
        }
    }
```

**ANDROID SERVICE**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PlaySoundService))]
namespace SaferProject.Droid.Services
{
    [Activity(Label = "PlaySoundService", NoHistory = true, Theme = "@style/MyTheme", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class PlaySoundService : IPlaySoundService
    {
        private static PlaySoundService _instance;
        readonly Ringtone _rt;
        bool IsPlaying;

        public static PlaySoundService GetInstance()
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new PlaySoundService();
            }
            return _instance;
        }

        public PlaySoundService()
        {
            AudioManager am = (AudioManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
            if (!am.RingerMode.Equals(2))
            {
                am.RingerMode = RingerMode.Normal;
                //am.SetVibrateSetting(VibrateType.Ringer, VibrateSetting.On);
            }

            Android.Net.Uri uri = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Ringtone);
            _rt = RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(MainActivity.instance.ApplicationContext, uri);
        }

        public Task PlaySystemSound()
        {
            _rt.Play();
            Vibration.Vibrate(500);
            SetServiceStatus(true);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopSystemSound()
        {
            Vibration.Cancel();
            _rt.Stop();
            SetServiceStatus(false);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void SetServiceStatus(bool isPlaying)
        {
            IsPlaying = isPlaying;
        }

        public bool GetServiceStatus()
        {
            return IsPlaying;
        }
    }
}
```

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
namespace SaferProject.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "SaferProject.Droid", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = false,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop)] //This is what controls orientation
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        public static MainActivity instance { set; get; }
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            instance = this;

            // Radio Button configuration
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags(new string[] { "RadioButton_Experimental" });

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
            //CreateNotificationFromIntent(Intent); //Local Notification - CRIADO NA MADRUGADA

            //################ Início OneSignal #################
            // Remove this method to stop OneSignal Debugging  
            OneSignal.Current.SetLogLevel(LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, LOG_LEVEL.NONE);

            OneSignal.Current.StartInit("417d7b75-ed42-4ca5-aed3-42612d260235")
             .InFocusDisplaying(OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
             .EndInit();
            //################# Fim OneSignal ###################
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

**ANDROID MANIFEST**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="6" android:versionName="1.2.0" package="br.com.safertechnology.saferproject" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <permission android:name="$br.com.safertechnology.saferproject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <application android:label="Safer" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:fullBackupContent="@xml/auto_backup_rules">
        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="$br.com.safertechnology.saferproject" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="$com.aolserra.sirene.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
</manifest>
```

**IOS SERVICE**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PlaySoundService))]
namespace SaferProject.iOS.Services
{
    public class PlaySoundService : IPlaySoundService
    {
        private static PlaySoundService _instance;
        readonly SystemSound Sound;
        bool IsPlaying;

        public static PlaySoundService GetInstance()
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new PlaySoundService();
            }
            return _instance;
        }

        public PlaySoundService()
        {
            AVAudioSession audioSession = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
            NSError error;
            audioSession.OverrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.Speaker, out error);

            Sound = new SystemSound(1151); //1304 (Alarm)
        }

        public Task PlaySystemSound()
        {
            Sound.PlaySystemSound();
            Vibration.Vibrate(500);
            SetServiceStatus(true);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task StopSystemSound()
        {
            Sound.Close();
            Vibration.Cancel();
            SetServiceStatus(false);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void SetServiceStatus(bool isPlaying)
        {
            IsPlaying = isPlaying;
        }

        public bool GetServiceStatus()
        {
            return IsPlaying;
        }
    }
}
```

**APPDELEGATE**

```
namespace SaferProject.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            //return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
            base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);

            //################ Início OneSignal #################
            // Remove this method to stop OneSignal Debugging  
            OneSignal.Current.SetLogLevel(LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, LOG_LEVEL.NONE);

            OneSignal.Current.StartInit("417d7b75-ed42-4ca5-aed3-42612d260235")
            .Settings(new Dictionary<string, bool>() {
                { IOSSettings.kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt, false },
                { IOSSettings.kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL, false } })
            .InFocusDisplaying(OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
            .EndInit();

            // The promptForPushNotificationsWithUserResponse function will show the iOS push notification prompt. We recommend removing the following code and instead using an In-App Message to prompt for notification permission (See step 7)
            OneSignal.Current.RegisterForPushNotifications();

            return true;
            //################# Fim OneSignal ###################
        }
    }
}
```

**INFO.PLIST**

[Info.Plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLaCa.png)

Comment: We can set `sound` when send message in  OneSignal  , did you check the docs : https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/sending-notifications ?

Comment: Thanks ColeX-MSFT but I can set the sound file. But I can't make it ring like it's a smartphone call bell. Am I right? I didn't find anything to that effect in the documentation.

Comment: You can download the `smartphone call bell` sound file from internet and add it into xcode project root ,then send the notifications with sounds :https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/customize-notification-sounds#2-add-sound-files-to-app.

Comment: Sorry, ColeX - MSFT...
But I don't think I can express my idea in English.
I need the notification sound to keep playing, in a loop, until the user taps the notification or opens the app.
In the prototype I created using OneSignal the message is received with the default notification ringtone. And this one plays the sound only once.
Could I explain better? I'm still learning English.

Comment: It is impossible , the notification can only play the sound once .